# Double integral of a minimum of two functions

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a problem in solving the integral :
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \min(h(t), h(s)) ds \ dt
$$
It can be simplified to
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^{h(t)} h(s) ds+\int_{h(t)}^1 h(t) ds \ dt = \int_0^1 \int_0^{h(t)} h(s) ds+h(t)-h^2(t)
$$

The function h is defined as $h : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ and is continuously differentiable.
The Integral should simplify to
$$
\int_0^1 h^2(t)dt
$$
But I don´t know if this is correct. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Whay is $min(h(t), h(s))=h(s)$ when $s <h(t)$?

Comment: Check your answer with $h\equiv2$.

Comment: is $h(t)$ monotonic?